# AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, configuration, servlet-3.0, spring-web

I want to know the purpose of below methods inside the class when the class extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

1. protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
       return new Class[0];
   }

   @Override

   2. protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { testAPI.class };
      }
      3.@Override
      protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
      }

Answer (score 0):

(1) wants a list of @Configuration (user) classes for creating a Root ApplicationContext and (2) wants a list of (user) classes for the AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.

So image you have several @Configuration classes coded somewhere, you can register them with:

```
@Override
protected final Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{CoreConfiguration.class, JpaConfiguration.class,
            ShiroSecurityConfig.class};
}
```